# consecutive coin counting in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to teach myself Python and I am working on modifying code that currently counts the number of heads and tails in a number of flips. I want it to count the number of consecutive heads. Here is the code I have so far.

```
def coinFlips(numberOfTosses):
    Heads = 0
    tossNum = 0
    while tossNumber < numberOfTosses:
        value = random.randint(1,2)
        if value == 1:
            numHeads = Heads + 1
        tossNum = tossNum + 1
    return (Heads, numTosses-Heads)
```

I feel like the answer is staring me in the face but I can't figure it out for the life of me!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BrenBarn instead of counting the number of heads/tails, I want it to return the longest "streak" of heads flipped in a row

Comment: you want output `A` but have coded for `B`, how do you expect A to come from B?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to `groupby` consecutive heads and tails and then find the `max` `len` of the `list` of tosses for only the heads (`1`):

```
import itertools as it
def coinFlips(numberOfTosses):
    flips = (random.randint(1,2) for _ in range(numberOfTosses))
    return max(len(list(tosses)) for coin, tosses in it.groupby(flips) if coin == 1)
            ^   ^   ^^    ^^                              ^^                   ^^
           max len list tosses                    groupby consecutive       only heads
```